# Why does the compiler not detect ClassCastException?

Tags: java

I know that in runtime something like this could throw a ClassCastException because Object is not a subclass of String.

```
String[] test = (String[]) new Object[10];
```

But I want to know why something like this is not detected when compiling?

Comment: It *is* detected; the compiler issues a *warning* of an unsafe cast, not an error.

Comment: Although it looks trivial in this situation, the right-hand side of the cast operator could've come from an `if` statement, or some other function call, or user input, or anything really, and it's impossible to statically check the safety of casts in general.

Comment: @Reilas No you didn’t. That’s a runtime exception, not a compiler error.

Comment: @user207421, that's a nuance, at this point.

Comment: @Reilas No it isn’t, it is a basic misunderstanding on your part. That distinction is what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `(String[]) new Object[10]` is not a compile error because the Java language specification defines it that way in [5.5.1. Reference Type Casting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1):

> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.
>
> [...]
>
> If S is an array type SC[], that is, an array of components of type SC:
>
> [...]
>
> - If T is an array type TC[], that is, an array of components of type TC, then a compile-time error occurs unless one of the following is true:
>
>   - [...]
>   - TC and SC are reference types and type SC can undergo casting conversion to TC.

In this case, the cast from the type `Object[]` to `String[]` (as in `SC[]` to `TC[]`) is not a compile error because the cast from `Object` to `String` (as in `SC` to `TC`) is not a compile error. This rule allows code like this:

```
Object[] s = new String[10];
String[] test = (String[])s;
```

This will not result in a compile error due to the definition above AND will not result in a `ClassCastException` because the variable `s` is referencing a `String[]` array. However, the following code

```
Object[] s = new Integer[10];
String[] test = (String[])s;
```

can still be compiled (due to the rules above), but will result in a `ClassCastException` as expected.